# I have been trying to create a csv file from python code on raspberry pi that can measure voltage, current, power, shunt voltage from ina219 sensor

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to create a csv file from a python code that is able to track the bus Voltage, bus current, power, and shunt voltage from a INA219 sensor that is connected to the raspberry pi3. This is the code that I have been working:

```
**#Importing libraries
import csv
from ina219 import INA219
from ina219 import DeviceRangeError
SHUNT_OHMS = 0.1
def read():
    ina = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS) #Measures the ina219
    ina.configure()
def measuring_things():
    try:
         print("Bus Voltage: %.3f V" % ina.voltage())
         print("Bus Current: %.3f mA" % ina.current())
         print("Power: %.3f mW" % ina.power())
         print("Shunt voltage: %.3f mV" % ina.shunt_voltage())
    except DeviceRangeError as e:
    # Current out of device range with specified shunt resistor  
        print(e)
    
f = open("SensorData.csv", "w", newline="") #Gives your .csv file a name
rc = csv.writer(f)
rc.writerow(["Distance from Sensor"]) #Heading
fields = ['Bus Voltage', 'Bus Current', 'Power', 'Shunt Voltage'] 
          
rc.writerow([read()])
rc.writerow(measuring_things())
f.close()**
```

I have changed the code around multiple times alongside created other codes and I keep getting an error from the ina.voltage, ina.current part no matter what I do. I keep getting an error saying:

```
============= RESTART: /home/pi/Downloads/scripts/SensorData.py =============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/scripts/SensorData.py", line 34, in <module>
    rc.writerow(measuring_things())
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/scripts/SensorData.py", line 16, in measuring_things
    print("Bus Voltage: %.3f V" % ina.voltage())
NameError: name 'ina' is not defined
```

I am getting irritating errors, they could be minor but I just feel stuck. My goal is to create a cvs file that is similar to this information :

```
============== RESTART: /home/pi/Downloads/scripts/Autogain.py ==============
Bus Voltage: 0.876 V
Bus Current: -0.098 mA
Power: 0.000 mW
Shunt voltage: -0.010 mV
```

This output I attached was done using python on the Raspberry pi 3 (with the INA219 sensor connected to it) by itself and not in hand converting it into a csv file.
The Rapberry system reads and is able to sense the INA219 sensor so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: You don’t return any thing to be actually written in your functions. For example - measuring_things() does not return anything which in python default to return None. Which you will try to right

Comment: When you define the variable `ina = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS)` you do so in the `read()` function. The variable `ina` is therefore in the local scope of the `read()` function and cannot be accessed in your `measuring_things()` function. You will need to define it either in the global scope of your script (main body) or pass it to/define it in the `measuring_things()` function, which will fix the error you have now. As mentioned by another commentor, you do not return anything from your functions, and writing to the file as you do at the end of the script will not work as you expect.

Comment: Thank you! I got it to run and it is creating a csv file but it is not displaying any information on the csv file. Thank you for working with me, I am new to python and raspberry pis. This is the code and output below.

Comment: def measuring_things():
    ina = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS) #Measures the ina219
    ina.configure()
    try:
         print("Bus Voltage: %.3f V" % ina.voltage())
         print("Bus Current: %.3f mA" % ina.current())
         print("Power: %.3f mW" % ina.power())
         print("Shunt voltage: %.3f mV" % ina.shunt_voltage())
    except DeviceRangeError as e:
    # Current out of device range with specified shunt resistor  
        print(e)

Comment: ============= RESTART: /home/pi/Downloads/scripts/SensorData.py =============
Bus Voltage: 0.876 V
Bus Current: -0.098 mA
Power: 0.000 mW
Shunt voltage: -0.010 mV
Would it be smart to just go into the terminal and change if via nano

Answer (score 2):

The "ina" variable is local, so the measuring_things() method doesn't have access to it

If your goal is to have a program that measures every so often and records those, file stuff goes inside the method that gets called on a timer.

```py
import csv
from ina219 import INA219
from ina219 import DeviceRangeError
import threading # for the timer
SHUNT_OHMS = 0.1


def measure_things():
    threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start() #run method every 5 seconds
    ina = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS)
    ina.configure()
    newRow=[]
    newRow.append("Bus Voltage: %.3f V" % ina.voltage())
    try:
        newRow.append("Bus Current: %.3f mA" % ina.current())
        newRow.append("Power: %.3f mW" % ina.power())
        newRow.append("Shunt voltage: %.3f mV" % ina.shunt_voltage())
    except DeviceRangeError as e:
        # Current out of device range with specified shunt resistor
        print(e)
    # save row to csv file
    with open(r'name', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(newRow)


measure_things()
#continue with other code if there is any
```

If your goal is to just measure once, remove threading